# Simulator can run project, but device can't did this

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios10

I need Your help! I have a project and when I try to run it in Simulator I have first and second error, but app build and run all the same. But when I try to do that in my phone(Iphone 6 with iOS 10.2), app didn't build and I have all errors.

> 1)The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to log in with account
>   'my acc'. An unexpected failure occurred while logging in (Underlying
>   error code -1009).
>
> 2)No profiles for 'name app' were found: Xcode couldn't find a
>   provisioning profile matching 'name app'.
>
> 3)Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS
>   10.2'

What's wrong? What should I do? Help me pls!

Comment: go to `xCode > Preferences > Account` and make sure your logged in with your AppleID. if you are, try removing and readding your account (export it first to save a backup)

Answer (score 1):

I just solved my case.
Here is my situation,

1. I had an AppleID for development which is not my main AppleID
2. I didn't add that ID after changed my iPhone from 6 to 7
3. when I tried to test my app on my iPhone Xcode gave me same error.

then what I did is:

1. checked account at Xcode Preference and made sure there is ID listed and signed in.
2. tried run my app on my iPhone, error again.
3. added ID to my iPhone
4. tried run my app, error again
5. restarted Xcode
6. tried my app, went good.